# WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS address won't print properly

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get the IP address of all the RDP connections logged into a computer. I'm using WTSEnumerateSessions and WTSQuerySessionInformation to retrieve a pointer to a WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS structure which contains the address. Here is part of the code :

```
WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
                           SessionNo,
                           WTSClientAddress,
                           &ppBuffer,
                           &pBytesReturned);

address = (WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS *)ppBuffer;

if (AF_INET == address->AddressFamily)
{
    printf("Client Address : %s\n", (LPSTR)address->Address);
}
else if (AF_INET6 == address->AddressFamily)
{
    //print IPV6
}
```

I can get the AddressFamily and the value is good, but when I try to print the Address I get gibberish. MSDN says the value is a null terminated string but it just won't print like it should. Here's the link :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383857(v=vs.85).aspx

I have a feeling I'm missing something here.

Comment: Yes, for IPV6 it is not a nul-terminated string as the page says. It is a byte array. Print each byte value separately in a loop.

Comment: Yes but the line "if (AF_INET == address->AdresseFamily)" garanties that it will only be IPV4 adresses. Printing it byte by byte will only work for IPV6 adresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not taking into account the following note in the [`WTS_INFO_CLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383861.aspx) documentation:

> WTSClientAddress
>   The network type and network address of the client. For more information, see WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS.
>
> **The IP address is offset by two bytes from the start of the Address member of the WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS structure.**

Also, despite what the documentation says, the IPv4 address is NOT a null-terminated string! It is actually the raw 4 bytes of the IPv4 address (just like the IPv6 address is raw bytes).

Try this instead:

```
WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
                           SessionNo,
                           WTSClientAddress,
                           &ppBuffer,
                           &pBytesReturned);

address = (WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS *)ppBuffer;

if (AF_INET == address->AddressFamily)
{
    printf("Client Address : %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
        address->Address[2], address->Address[3], address->Address[4], address->Address[5]);
}
else if (AF_INET6 == address->AddressFamily)
{
    //print IPV6
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thanks ! And the IPV6 address is offset by two bytes too. (for anyone else coming with the same problem)